# Problem Installing ClickOnce App VB.Net WinForm

Tags: visual-studio-2019, clickonce, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to install an application that I created in VB.Net VS2019, this app is an empty form with an icon on the form and no code at all.

[image: Form to deploy]

The app is being deployed to a shared drive.

When I execute the .exe or the .application the ClickOnce Installer is unable to download the icon of the form.

[image]

After a couple minutes waiting this are the errors I get:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

TLDR: I cant install the application because I cant download the icon according to the error, similar apps can be installed without a problem, this happens only with new apps.

Things I've tried:

- Run the .application
- Run the .exe
- Try in several different client computers
- Change Framework from 4.6.1 all the way to 4.5
- Checked my connection
- Checked accessibility to the folder
- Creating a brand new empty app to deploy

In addition I have other ClickOnce apps deployed in the same path just different folders and they all are working properly and I can install those without a problem.

I'm using same settings for every app deployed.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, the problem was that the icon that is used on the shortcut of the app was 66KB, and when I checked all the other app's icons they were like 2KB on average, when I swapped icons the application was installed immediately.

TLDR: Icon was too heavy and the app was unable to download it. (66KB)

Solution: change icons.